# How to make HTML form fields automatically change when an option selected on a select field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Let's say I have a form like this in my CodeIgniter project.

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <select>
        <?php foreach($status_list as $status): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $status->id; ?>"><?php echo $status->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <!-- Show this only if status type is, let's say "E" -->
    <input type="text" name="E_happened">
    <!-- Show this only if status type is, let's say "S" -->
    <input type="text" name="S_happened">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

What I want to do is if an user select one status, according to the it's type, show a text field to get an input.

I've made a way to get a type of the status like this: http://localhost/myapp/index.php/status/type/{status_id} where users can pass status ID and it will "echo" the type of the status.

I want to receive it back to the HTML page via a JavaScript method and show those text input fields. How do I do that?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Better if you will assign status type in option attribute, for why are you want do additional request to the server? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As you have `jQuery` tag, so i suggest you this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var inp = this.value.trim();
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"][name^="'+inp+'"]').show().siblings(':text').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the sample flow as per you want to do. hope this will helpful for you.

**PHP:**

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <select>
        <?php foreach($status_list as $status): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $status->id; ?>"><?php echo $status->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <!-- Show this only if status type is, let's say "E" -->
    <input type="text" id="E_happened" name="E_happened">
    <!-- Show this only if status type is, let's say "S" -->
    <input type="text" id="S_happened" name="S_happened">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** :

```
  $('select').change(function(){
     var statusId = $(this).val();
     var statusType = $.get("http://localhost/myapp/index.php/status/type/"+statusId);
     if(statusType == 'E')
     {
       $('#E_happened').value("what do you want here");
     }
     if(statusType == 'S')
     {
        $('#S_happened').value("what do you want here");
      }
   });
```